# lightning:navigation not working in community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, navigation

Here is component I want to navigate to, named TestCmp:

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="someId" type="Id" />
    {!v.someId}
</aura:component>
```

And here is code of component, from which I want to havigate:

```
<lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>


component.find("navService").navigate({
            type: "standard__component",
            attributes: { componentName: "c:TestCmp" },
            state: { someId: "xx" }
        });
```

When I press the button (this code is executed) nothing happens. No error message, nothing in console. Neither in community builder nor for community user.
What I also find that in this code 'finally' is never executed:

```
component.find("navService").generateUrl({
            type: "standard__recordPage",
            "attributes": {
                "recordId": accountId,
                "objectApiName": "Account",
                "actionName": "view"
            }
        }).finally(function(value) {
            console.log(value);
        });
```

If I log result of generateUrl function, it says Promise object with state 'pending'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

> These navigation resources are supported only in Lightning Experience
>   and the Salesforce mobile app. They’re not supported in other
>   containers, such as Lightning Components for Visualforce, Lightning
>   Out, or Communities. This is true even if you access these containers
>   inside Lightning Experience or the Salesforce mobile app.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/components_navigation.htm